# Yii2 phpdoc for Yii::$app->passport

Tags: yii2, phpdoc

My IDE PHPStorm marks next line as mistake (word "password")

```
Yii::$app->passport->getLoginUrl($Url);
```

How can i write phpdoc for it.

May be in suchway or how?

```
/** @var $Yii::$app->passport array */
Yii::$app->passport->getLoginUrl($Url);
```

Comment: by writing 'word "password"' did you mean `passport`? because the word `password` doesn't appear here anywhere :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can find the solution for this in [Yii 2.0 Cookbook - IDE autocompletion for custom components](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/ide-autocompletion/)

> Using custom Yii class
>
> The best way to give IDE some hints is to use your own Yii file which
>   isn't actually used when running code. This file could be named
>   `Yii.php` and the content could be the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Yii bootstrap file.
 * Used for enhanced IDE code autocompletion.
 */
class Yii extends \yii\BaseYii
{
    /**
     * @var BaseApplication|WebApplication|ConsoleApplication the application instance
     */
    public static $app;
}

/**
 * Class BaseApplication
 * Used for properties that are identical for both WebApplication and ConsoleApplication
 *
 * @property \app\components\RbacManager $authManager The auth manager for this application. Null is returned if auth manager is not configured. This property is read-only. Extended component.
 * @property \app\components\Mailer $mailer The mailer component. This property is read-only. Extended component.
 */
abstract class BaseApplication extends yii\base\Application
{
}

/**
 * Class WebApplication
 * Include only Web application related components here
 *
 * @property \app\components\User $user The user component. This property is read-only. Extended component.
 * @property \app\components\MyResponse $response The response component. This property is read-only. Extended component.
 * @property \app\components\ErrorHandler $errorHandler The error handler application component. This property is read-only. Extended component.
 */
class WebApplication extends yii\web\Application
{
}

/**
 * Class ConsoleApplication
 * Include only Console application related components here
 *
 * @property \app\components\ConsoleUser $user The user component. This property is read-only. Extended component.
 */
class ConsoleApplication extends yii\console\Application
{
}
```

> In the above PHPDoc of `BaseApplication`, `WebApplication`,
>   `ConsoleApplication` will be used by IDE to autocomplete your custom
>   components described via `@property`.
>
> **Note**: To avoid "Multiple Implementations" PHPStorm warning and make
>   autocomplete faster exclude or "Mark as Plain Text"
>   `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php` file.
>
> That's it. Now `Yii::$app->user` will be our `\app\components\User`
>   component instead of default one. The same applies for all other
>   `@property`-declared components.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).